# B-splines and Catmull-Clark subdives. What are the similarities between them?

Tags: parametric, curves, bezier-curve, spline

I've a special question between mathematics and 3d.
I struggle for two days understand relation between B-splines and Catmull-Clark subdivs. Everywhere wrote the Catmul-Clark subdivs is based on bicubic B-spline surface but I can't understand how. I can't find direct dependence. Only [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/10_Subdivision.pdf)
I met a mention about three strange coefficient - 1/8,6/8,1/8, but I not seen that in B-spline theory. I did a experiment with cubic B-spline and three  poligons with CC  and they was equal with the same cage. I'm not expert in spline, but I seen many papers about that theme and I can't find info. :((

UPD For example this my comparision for 3 poligons with CC subdiv and cage (yellow) + not clamped (clamped has other curvature) B-spline degree 3 (black):

[image]

It looks as the same! But why?

Comment: We'll never know about this. :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients [1,6,1]/8 for even control points, as well as [4,4]/8 for odd ones, appear in the rows of the local subdivision matrix $H$, which is derived from the matrix form of the parametric bicubic B-Spline patch S(u,v). See the derivation in the original 1978 paper:

[https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/CS284/PAPERS/CatmullClark_SDSurf.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Esequin/CS284/PAPERS/CatmullClark_SDSurf.pdf)

Eq. 1 shows the matrix form of the *parametric definition* of S(u,v), which is reformulated to a *recursive (subdivision)* formulation that maps a 4x4 control point matrix $G$ to a matrix of a refined control point mesh $G_1$ according to Eq. 3, using the local subdivison matrix $H$ (in the paper it's called "splitting matrix").

This matrix also appears (in normalized form including the factor $1/8$) in the Stanford lecture slides you linked (Slide 74).